# Extract data from string in python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, floating-point

I have a .csv file with data constructed as `[datetime, "(data1, data2)"]` in rows and I have managed to import the data into python as `time` and `temp`, the problem I am facing is how do I seperate the `temp` string into two `new_temp` columns in float format to use for plotting later on?

My code so far is:

```
import csv
import matplotlib.dates as dates

def getColumn(filename, column):
    results = csv.reader(open('logfile.csv'), delimiter = ",")
    return [result[column] for result in results]
time = getColumn("logfile.csv",0)
temp = getColumn("logfile.csv",1)
new_time = dates.datestr2num(time)
new_temp = [???]
```

When I `print temp` I get `['(0.0, 0.0)', '(64.4164, 66.2503)', '(63.4768, 65.4108)', '(62.7148, 64.6278)', '(62.0408, 63.9625)', '(61.456, 63.2638)', '(61.0234, 62.837)', '(60.6823, 62.317)',...etc]`

If anyone can help me then thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse a tuple from a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763116/parse-a-tuple-from-a-string)

Comment: As a side note, you should read the CSV only once and then extract the columns. Currently you read the whole file over and over.

Comment: I checket that solution and wrote make_tuple(temp) and get the error: ValueError: malformed string. And i also tried the tuple(int(x) for x in temp[1:-1].split(',')) and get the error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Is there any problem with my solution? It should work.

Comment: when i change the "string" into my "temp" variable then i get the error: TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: As an extra info then here is a drive [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-yaioMxfCgyVEhwOTBiX2JNbUk) to the logfile then you could try running the solution with the given code.

Comment: You can try to replace string with str(temp). Maybe this is enough to make it work.

Comment: Thanks man that seems to have made the magic.

Comment: Cool, glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this code:

```
import re
string = "['(0.0, 0.0)', '(64.4164, 66.2503)', '(63.4768, 65.4108)', '(62.7148, 64.6278)', '(62.0408, 63.9625)', '(61.456, 63.2638)', '(61.0234, 62.837)', '(60.6823, 62.317)']"
data = re.findall('[+-]?\d+\.\d+e?[+-]?\d*', string)
data = zip(data[0::2], data[1::2])
print [float(d[0]) for d in data]
print [float(d[1]) for d in data]
```

Comment: This will fail if you have some differently formatted floats (e.g. 5.2456e10). Better use Python's built in parser for evaluating Python expressions in strings as suggested in the comments.

Comment: No special format was mentioned but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Does it work with 5.2456e-10, 5.2456e+9, -5.2456e-10, .1, 1.?

Comment: Yes, now it does, but I am sure you will find another case ;-) Deutsche Korrektheit was?

Comment: Signs can also be leading? Ja, genau :-D!

Comment: Ok use a parser if this does not suit your needs.

Comment: I found that the suggestion of user3387223 was quite important so I improved the solution again to allow negative values.

Answer (score 1):

Going from the answer in 
[Parse a tuple from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763116/parse-a-tuple-from-a-string)

```
from ast import literal_eval as make_tuple
temp = ['(0.0, 0.0)', '(64.4164, 66.2503)', '(63.4768, 65.4108)', '(62.7148, 64.6278)', '(62.0408, 63.9625)', '(61.456, 63.2638)', '(61.0234, 62.837)', '(60.6823, 62.317)']

tuples = [make_tuple(stringtuple) for stringtuple in temp]
```

and you have an array of tuples of doubles.

*I undeleted the post and made it a full answer, because apparently it wasn't clear enough to reference the other post.*

Comment: If it has already been answered, post it as a comment, not an answer. E.g. Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763116/parse-a-tuple-from-a-string

Comment: @user3387223: Thanks for sharing this.