# UserError returns tuple instead of string inside the try - odoo 9 and 10

Tags: exception, odoo, alert

Here is my code

```
try:
     raise UserError(_('foo'))
except Exception as e:
     raise UserError(_(str(e)))
```

The warning box shows **(u'foo', None)** instead of **foo**.

> **Warning**
>       *(u'foo', None)*
>
> **[OK]**

But exception shows correctly
Example

```
try:
     print 100 / 0
     raise UserError(_('foo'))
except Exception as e:
     raise UserError(_(str(e)))
```

Result is

> **Warning** 
>   *integer division or modulo by zero*  
>   **[OK]**

This Problem is only inside the try.
Please tell me what can I do?

Comment: i didn't understand what you want exactly but did you import all what is needed to use UserError and _  to translate

Comment: what's wrong with `UserError(_(str('foo')))`?

Comment: The alert is working, but it shows  (u'foo', None) instead of foo inside the try

Answer (score 0):

I solved by [parse_tuple()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763116/#44537379) function.

```
# ...
except Exception as e:
    parsed = parse_tuple(e)
    if parsed:
        raise UserError(_(str(parsed[0])))
    raise UserError(_(str(e)))
```

EDIT:

```
raise UserError(e.args[0])
```