# Read tuples from text file

Tags: python, tuples

I need to read tuples from a txt.  I tried with numpy (using genfromtxt) but it didn't work (or at least, I don't know how).
This is is my txt:

```
(0,0) (0,0) (1,0) (2,3)
(1,0) (1,1) (1,1) (3,3)
(2,0) (1,2) (2,1) (4,4)
(3,0) (2,2) (3,1) (5,5)
```

I want to read one by one this columns and get a list of tuples:
Trying with numpy I have this:

```
import numpy as np
File = np.genfromtxt('file.txt',delimiter=' ', dtype= tuple)
```

But it returns a list of lists with bytes type elements.

Obviously I can change the way the data is stored in the txt. I just need to get a list of tuples (or a list of lists) from a txt.

Comment: have you tried parsing it as tuple from existing python lib `from ast import literal_eval`
Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/9763133/3521116

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try regular expression too here:

```
import re
pattern='\((\d+,\d)\)'
with open('demo.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        data=re.findall(pattern,line)
        data_1=[]
        for item in data:
            data_1.append(tuple(map(lambda x:int(x),item.split(','))))
        if data_1:
            print(data_1)
```

output:

```
[(0, 0), (0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 3)]
[(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 1), (3, 3)]
[(2, 0), (1, 2), (2, 1), (4, 4)]
[(3, 0), (2, 2), (3, 1), (5, 5)]
```

Or even better:

```
import re
pattern='\((\d+,\d)\)'
with open('demo.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        data=re.findall(pattern,line)
        data_1=[tuple(map(lambda x:int(x),item.split(','))) for item in data]
        if data_1:
            print(data_1)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple way without using any libraries:

```
tuples = []
for t in open('input.txt').read().split():
    a, b = t.strip('()').split(',')
    tuples.append((int(a), int(b)))
```

List comprehension equivalent:

```
[tuple(int(i) for i in t.strip('()').split(',')) for t in open('input.txt').read().split()]
```

With `input.txt` being the data provided in the question, this is the output:

```
[(0, 0), (0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 3), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 1), (3, 3), (2, 0), (1, 2), (2, 1), (4, 4), (3, 0), (2, 2), (3, 1), (5, 5)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this one, although it does not use the `numpy` library:

```
from ast import literal_eval as createTuple

tupleList = []

with open("test.txt","r") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        line = line.split()
        for l in line:
            tupleList.append(createTuple(l))

print(tupleList)
```

Format of input file:

```
(0,0) (0,0) (1,0) (2,3)
(1,0) (1,1) (1,1) (3,3)
(2,0) (1,2) (2,1) (4,4)
(3,0) (2,2) (3,1) (5,5)
```

Output (list of tuples):

```
[(0, 0), (0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 3), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 1), (3, 3), (2, 0), (1, 2), (2, 1), (4, 4), (3, 0), (2, 2), (3, 1), (5, 5)]
```