# how to read text file each tuples and integers are splited properly

Tags: python

I have a text file (target file of NWPU VHR-10 dataset) that included 2 tuples and one integer for each line e.g each line has the text like this:

(563,478),(630,573),1

Now I wanna find out how to split and read it like two tuples and one integer. e.g:

tuple 1: (563,478)
tuple 2: (630,573)
int: 1

thanks

Comment: It's not clear what is your question,  Do you want to split the read in `lines` to what kind of format?  Can you show what's you got then?

Comment: Have you tried to split one line at commas, strip the parentheses from each part, convert the results to integers, and combine the first and second, and the third and fourth integer to tuples, and then repeat this for every line?

Comment: Try adaping some solutions from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48094176/read-tuples-from-text-file?rq=1

Comment: @DanielHao I wanna all formats to be integers in tuples. 2 tuples consist of 2 integers and an integer. This is after I read the lines in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for @mkrieger1 the solution I found was this

```
    import re

    for line in target_file:
        line = re.sub(r"([()])", "", line)
        lst = list(map(int, line.split(',')))
        k, t, p = (lst[0], lst[1]), (lst[2], lst[3]), lst[4]
        print(k)
        print(t)
        print(p)
```

Comment: `ast.literal_eval()` seems like a simpler solution.