# why sorted() does not sort tuples?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list with 40 values in different formats like below:

```
line =['2005:450243780097359872', 'consumer', '(0, 0.038374472)', '(1, 0.038374227)', '(2, 0.46275997)', '(3, 0.03837424)', '(4, 0.038374268)', '(5, 0.038374446)', '(6, 0.038374227)', '(7, 0.038374294)', '(8, 0.03837436)', '(9, 0.038374227)', '(10, 0.038374227)', '(11, 0.03837425)', '(12, 0.038374335)', '(13, 0.038374227)', '(14, 0.038374227)', '(0, 0.038374472)', '(1, 0.038374227)', '(2, 0.46275997)', '(3, 0.03837424)', '(4, 0.038374268)', '(5, 0.038374446)', '(6, 0.038374227)', '(7, 0.038374294)', '(8, 0.03837436)', '(9, 0.038374227)', '(10, 0.038374227)', '(11, 0.03837425)', '(12, 0.038374335)', '(13, 0.038374227)', '(14, 0.038374227)', '355', '120', '110', '2014-03-30 12:10:56', '0', '0', 'consumer', '2005:450217727324856320']
```

I want to keep the second element of this list and also the tuple which has the biggest value of in terms of its second element. in short, I want this:

```
['consumer' , '(2, 0.46275997)']
```

this is the my code:

```
St = [line[1] , sorted(line[2:17] , reverse=True, key=lambda x:x[1])[0]]
```

and this is the result I get:

```
['consumer', '(9, 0.038374227)']
```

Can anybody explain why `sorted()` does not return what is expected? probably troubleshooting my code?
Thanks

Comment: That's a str, not a tuple. Where do you get the data from?

Comment: Also it's better to use `max` instead of `sorted` in this case.

Comment: I get the data from a csv file.

Comment: Then you'd need to convert them to tuples first.

Comment: max returns ```['consumer', '(9, 0.038374227)']```

Comment: can you elaborate on that? I tried to use ```max``` and convert the data like this : ```St = [line[1] , max(tuple(line[2:17]) , key=lambda x:x[1])]``` the results didnot change, though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197978/discussion-between-pie-ton-and-user202729).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763116/parse-a-tuple-from-a-string

Comment: this can turn strings to tuples one at a time. Is there another way that take in a bunch of strings and turn them into tuples? my data set is rather large and it seems so time-consuming to to that for every single string in each row.

Comment: How long does it take?

Comment: my dataset has 12+million rows, and each row has 15 of these tuples. I assume I will have to use nested loops to turn the strings into tuples.