# How to read a file of tuples?

Tags: python, numpy, file, io

I have a .txt file made like this:

```
(12,13,14,15)
(1,2,4,5)
(1,2,3,4,5)
```

and so on. I would like to store the file into a numpy array of shape (N,4), discarding those tuples which have more than 4 elements.
I've tried with
`np.genfromtxt('filename.txt', delimiter=',', invalid_raise=False)`
but I get NaN for the first and the last term of each line due to the presence of '(' and ')'. How can I solve it?

Comment: that's not `csv` format.  Use basic python to get a list of list, and make the array from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a simple in built library used to get tuple from string.

```
from ast import literal_eval as make_tuple
tuple_list=[]
a=open("try.txt","r").readlines()
for i in a:
    if i!="":
        temp=make_tuple(i)
        if len(temp)<=4:
            tuple_list.append(temp)
            
print(tuple_list)
```

try.txt consists of your tuples
and final result is a list of all the tuples with length less than equal to 4.

output:

```
[(12, 13, 14, 15), (1, 2, 4, 5)]
```

Ref: [Parse a tuple from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763116/parse-a-tuple-from-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

You first need to remove the curved braces which can be achieved with the `strip` method of str:

```
"(1,2,3,4)".strip("()")
# "1,2,3,4"
```

Here is a working solution:

```py
import numpy as np 

with open("filename.txt") as f:
  data = f.readlines()
  data = [line.strip("()\n").split(",") for line in data]
  array = np.array(data).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution:

```
import numpy as np
#Read and split files with new line character
with open("temp.txt","r") as f:
    temp = f.read().split("\n")
# convert tuple stored as string to tuple whoes length = 4
temp = [eval(elements) for elements in temp if len(eval(elements))==4]
# convert list to numpy array of size (N,4)
arr=np.array(temp)
```