# How to read an optional tuple of integers using a regex with python?

Tags: python, regex-group

I try to implement a regex to read lines such as :

```
*     DCH  :   0.80000000                             *
*      PYR  : 100.00000000                            *
*    Bond (  1,   0)  :   0.80000000                  *
*     Angle (  1,   0,   2)  : 100.00000000           *
```

To that end, I wrote the following regex. It works, but I would like to have some feedback about the way to get the integer numbers in parenthesis. On the lines 3 and 4 above, the part with the integers between parenthesis (a kind of tuple of integers) is optional.

I have to define several groups to be able to define that tuple of integer as optional and to manage the fact that that tuple may contain 2, 3 or 4 integers.

```
In [64]: coord_patt = re.compile(r"\s+(\w+)\s+(\(((\s*\d+),?){2,4}\))?\s+:\s+(\d+.\d+)")

In [65]: line2 = "*     Angle (  1,   0,   2)  : 100.00000000           *"

In [66]: m = coord_patt.search(line2)

In [67]: m.groups()
Out[67]: ('Angle', '(  1,   0,   2)', '   2', '   2', '100.00000000')
```

Another example :

```
In [68]: line = "         *                 Bond (  1,   0)  :   0.80000000           *"

In [69]: m = coord_patt.search(line)
    
In [71]: m.groups()
Out[71]: ('Bond', '(  1,   0)', '   0', '   0', '0.80000000')
```

As you can see it works, but I do not understand why, in the groups, I got only the last integer and not the each integer separately ? Is there a way to get that integers individually or to avoid to define all that groups and catch only the group 2 which is a string of the tuple which can be easily read otherwise.

Comment: related? [Parse a tuple from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9763116/10197418) - solutions there however might not fit in your one big regex pattern (not sure if that is a must?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in [Capturing repeating subpatterns in Python regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9765390), the `re` module doesn't support repeated captures, but [`regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) does.

Here are two solutions, one based on `regex`, the other on `re` and the safe evaluation of the tuple when one is encountered.

### Setup

```py
txt = r"""*     DCH  :   0.80000000                             *
*      PYR  : 100.00000000                            *
*    Bond (  1,   0)  :   0.80000000                  *
*     Angle (  1,   0,   2)  : 100.00000000           *
"""
```

### Using `regex`

```py
import regex

p = regex.compile(r'\s+(\w+)\s+(?:\((?:\s*(\d+),?){2,4}\))?\s+:\s+(\d+.\d+)')

for s in txt.splitlines():
    if m := p.search(s):
        name = m.group(1)
        tup = tuple(int(k) for k in m.captures(2) if k.isnumeric())
        val = float(m.group(3))
        print(f'{name!r}\t{tup!r}\t{val!r}')
```

Prints:

```py
'DCH'   ()  0.8
'PYR'   ()  100.0
'Bond'  (1, 0)  0.8
'Angle' (1, 0, 2)   100.0
```

### Using `re`

```py
import re
import ast

p = re.compile(r'\s+(\w+)\s+(\((?:\s*\d+,?){2,4}\))?\s+:\s+(\d+.\d+)')

for s in txt.splitlines():
    if m := p.search(s):
        name, tup, val = m.groups()
        tup = ast.literal_eval(tup) if tup is not None else ()
        val = float(val)
        print(f'{name!r}\t{tup!r}\t{val!r}')
```

Prints:

```py
'DCH'   ()  0.8
'PYR'   ()  100.0
'Bond'  (1, 0)  0.8
'Angle' (1, 0, 2)   100.0
```

Comment: Thank you also for the `:=` operator. I had missed that new feature of 3.8 !

Comment: `regex` seems to be 2 times faster than `re`. Is it general, is that `regex` should be preferred to `re` ?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably far more elaborate than what you are looking for, but I thought I would present it anyway as something to be added to your "toolbox" for it will handle even more complicated situations as it is actually a top-down parser and thus able to handle languages that cannot be defined by regular expressions.

```py
from typing import NamedTuple
import re

lines = """
DCH  :   0.80000000
PYR  : 100.00000000
Bond (  1,   0)  :   0.80000000
Angle (  1,   0,   2)  : 100.00000000
"""

class Token(NamedTuple):
    type: str
    value: str

# The order of these matters because they are tried in turn:
token_specification = [
    ('WORD', r'[a-zA-Z]\w*'), # cannot use `\w+` since that would also match numbers
    ('COLON', r':'),
    ('LPAREN', r'\('),
    ('RPAREN', r'\)'),
    ('FLOAT', r'\d+\.\d+'),
    ('INT', r'\d+'),
    ('COMMA', r','),
    ('SKIP', r'\s+'),
    ('ERROR', r'.') # anything else
]
tok_regex = re.compile('|'.join('(?P<%s>%s)' % pair for pair in token_specification))

def generate_tokens(code):
    scanner = tok_regex.scanner(code)
    for m in iter(scanner.match, None):
        type = m.lastgroup
        if type == 'SKIP':
            continue
        if type == 'FLOAT':
            value = float(m.group()) # or just m.group()
        elif type == 'INT':
            value = int(m.group()) # or just m.group()
        else:
            value = m.group()
        yield Token(type, value)
    yield Token('EOF', 'EOF') # end of string


class Evaluator():

    def parse(self, s):
        self.token_iterator = generate_tokens(s)
        self.next_token()
        try:
            while self.token.type != 'EOF': # not end of string
                yield self.evaluate()
        except Exception:
            pass

    def evaluate(self):
        # current token should be WORD
        word_value = self.token.value
        self.accept('WORD') # throw exception if not 'WORD'
        i_list = self.optional_int_list()
        # current token should be a colon
        self.accept('COLON')
        # current token should be a float
        float_value = self.token.value
        self.accept('FLOAT')
        return word_value, i_list, float_value

    def optional_int_list(self):
        i_list = []
        if self.token.type == 'LPAREN':
            self.next_token()
            # current token should be an integer
            i_list.append(self.token.value)
            self.accept('INT')
            while self.token.type == 'COMMA':
                self.next_token()
                # next token should be an integer
                i_list.append(self.token.value)
                self.accept('INT')
            # next token should be a right parentheses:
            self.accept('RPAREN')
        return i_list

    def next_token(self):
        self.token = next(self.token_iterator, None)

    def accept(self, type):
        if self.token.type != type:
            raise Exception(f'Error: was expecting a {type}, got {self.token.type}')
        self.next_token()

evaluator = Evaluator()
for word_value, integer_values, float_value in evaluator.parse(lines):
     print(word_value, integer_values, float_value)
```

Prints:

```
DCH [] 0.8
PYR [] 100.0
Bond [1, 0] 0.8
Angle [1, 0, 2] 100.0
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert integers inside parenthesis which are currently `string` to `int` you have to convert it to `tuple`.
It will store all the tuples in a list which you can retrieve later to do operations on it.

```
import re
from ast import literal_eval as make_tuple

lines = [
    "*    DCH  :   0.80000000                       *",
    "*    PYR  : 100.00000000                       *",
    "    Bond (  1,   0)  :   0.80000000                  *",
    "*     Angle (  1,   0,   2)  : 100.00000000           *",
]

coord_patt = re.compile(r"\s+(\w+)\s+(\(((\s*\d+),?){2,4}\))?\s+:\s+(\d+.\d+)")
tuples = list()
for line in lines:
    temp = coord_patt.search(line)

    if temp.groups()[1] is not None:
        tuples.append(make_tuple(temp.groups()[1]))

print(tuples)

for tup in tuples:
    for element in tup:
        print(element, end=' ')

    print()
```

Here's the output

```
Output:
[(1, 0), (1, 0, 2)]
1 0
1 0 2
```

Comment: seems a repeat of the second part of my answer, no?

Comment: @PierreD I am not sure why you felt that way, but I was already writing my answer when you posted the answer.

Comment: no worries, it looked quite similar. But then again, the link given by @MrFuppes comment (which I hadn't seen until now) is also pointing to the same approach... LOL, I guess there are only so many ways to skin a cat...